# Open URL in a browser and not application (Prevent deep linking)

Tags: android, url, deep-linking

I'm trying to open a URL in a web browser (Chrome, or anything else) and prevent it to be opened in an application.
For example: [Asos Item URL](http://www.asos.com/asos/asos-oversized-coat-with-funnel-neck/prd/8471132)

If you have ASOS app installed, and you try to open the URL within android application, it won't be opened in Chrome, but rather in ASOS application.

Hope there's a way to achieve it

Comment: See this on how to stop it if you are the developer of the app

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057244/how-to-prevent-deep-linking-from-mobile-site-in-android